# Super basic question on linking domain to server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, webserver, reverse-proxy

I have a super basic question. I have a GoDaddy account set up with subdomain *xxx.mydomain.com*. I also have some services running in an AWS instance on *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7000*. My question is, what do I do to configure so that when people click `xxx.mydomain.com` it goes to *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7000*?

I am not talking about domain forwarding. In fact, I also hope to do the same for *yyy.mydomain.com* to link it to *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000*. I am running Ngnix in *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx*. Maybe I need to configure something there?

Answer (score 0):

**You want a reverse proxy.**

Add two *A-records* to your DNS configuration to map the subdomains to the IP address of the AWS instance. With GoDaddy, put `xxx` / `yyy` in the *"Host"* field and the IP address in the *"Points to"* field. <sup><sub>([more info](https://www.godaddy.com/help/create-a-subdomain-4080))</sub></sup>

Since you already have Nginx running, you can use it as a reverse proxy for the two subdomains. Therefore, add two more *server* blocks to Nginx's configuration file. A very simple one could look like this:

```
http {
    # ...
    server {
        server_name xxx.mydomain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:7000;
        }
    }
    server {
        server_name yyy.mydomain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to rewrite some headers depending on your services/applications <sup><sub>([more info](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/))</sub></sup>. Also, consider to use Nginx for SSL termination <sup><sub>([more info](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/))</sub></sup>.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I did all this but somehow I still get this "[site] took too long to response" error msg.....

Comment: @MengWeeTan My answer assumed all services are on the same machine and accessible directly over *localhost*. In case you are using containers, the networking would be a bit different. We don't have much information to find the problem: Verify whether the DNS-Records are published and refer to the correct IP address. Check if the relevant ports (80, 443) are open on that server (VM and AWS firewall). Make sure Nginx is actually listening on these ports. If you get *502 Bad Gateway*, make sure Nginx can access the resource under the configured URL and the respective service is actually running.